# Unhandled JS Exception: babelHelpers.jsx is not a function

Tags: react-native

I have created build with bundled code in main.jsbundle, everything works well on simulator and also on iPhone when it's installed directly, but after I have submitted build to fabric.io to beta service, application is failing to run with this exception:

```
Fatal Exception: RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: babelHelpers.jsx is not a function. (In 'babelHelpers.jsx(i["default"],{})', 'babelHelpers.jsx' is undefined)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform-react-inline-elements` depends on `babelHelpers.jsx`. We don't ship all the helpers on react-native but a reduced set which doesn't include that function.